# Does devices have registers?

Tags: hardware, device, cpu, processor, cpu-registers

I have always heard registers as `CPU registers`. Does other devices or hardware also have its own registers like a decoder hardware, a display device, a DMA controller?

If so, how are the values stored in those device registers passed to cpu registers in case they are necessary for an `instruction execution`? Can any of you explain, if possible with a real world example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some devices have dedicated registers and others don't.  Some of those other ones have register-like components that get lumped into the "register" category even though they shouldn't really be there.

I/O between the device and the rest of the system can happen in a number of ways, including port based IO (a system similar to, but seperate from, typical memory access), memory based IO (use of specific addresses as control addresses, into and from which data can be moved to and from the device), or direct memory access (in which the device is capable of autonomously accessing system memory through the memory bus).

A friend of mine wrote a Port IO based SATA HDD driver, however most modern OSs use DMA for those because it's less CPU intensive.

Devices like graphics cards, which contain their own processing units, contain true registers used for processing.  They, to the best of my knowledge, are not available directly to the processor, but the processor can (presumably through a combination of port based IO and DMA) provide executable data to the GPU which it can then execute, and it can store the output of its computations on the onboard device memory, which can be accessed through DMA.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  Look up the definition of the word register.  A sound card or chip, has one or many registers that are used to control the volume for example.  Individual registers written in a single memory or I/O transaction.

Most peripherals have registers, some have banks of memory.  Some the memory is accessed one item at a time using registers (write the offset to an offset register, write or read the data using a data register, repeat) or the bank of memory is mapped somehow into the memory space of the host.  Again think of a sound card or video card, individual registers are used to control various things, width, height, depth, frequency, etc.  For sound cards the mixer controls, etc are through registers.  Moving video data, pixels, characters, textures, etc to video memory or to a gpu that then does something for you, can and is done through banks of memory that are mapped into the host address space.  Sometimes the amount of memory on the peripheral is larger than the bank of host address space available so registers in the peripheral are used to control which bank of peripheral memory is available through the hole in the hosts address space.

You may also find it interesting that regiters in a cpu, a processor, are often implemented  using an sram, with an address and data bus and read/write control signals.